# Need Xpath for a button in the input tag

Tags: selenium, button, xpath

I am new to the selenium.I have to click a button using its xpath but I am not able to click it as I am unable to get the xpath.PFA the screenshot of the  html structure:
[image]
the name of the button is "Build Form".

`XPath`

```
//table[@id='fluid_layout_option']/tbody//tr/td//table/tbod‌​y/tr/input[@class='s‌​mall']
```

Comment: It seem to be simple case. Why are you not able to get `XPath`? Show what you have tried

Comment: "//table[@id='fluid_layout_option']/tbody//tr/td//table/tbody/tr/input[@class='small']"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xPath `"//input[@value='Build Form']"` to click on the button

Answer (score 0):

xpath = //input[@value = 'Build Form']